# Editar registro selecionado

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu exibo registros vindos do banco em td's, em cada registro tem um botão de editar que abre a tela de edição, porém não sei como posso exibir nessa tela os dados do registro que cliquei, para editar e salvar.

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou **(código fonte)**, você consegue pegar o `id` da informação selecionada?

Comment: Eu ainda não tentei nada, não sei como posso fazer. E consigo selecionar o id.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude http://blogwebdesignmicrocamp.com.br/programacao/php-instrucao-update-como-editar-os-registros/

Comment: de forma simples,  no link do editar pode ficar <a href='editar.php?id=$codigorecuperado'>Editar</a>

Comment: @R.Santos, isso ajudou sim. Após finalizar, insiro o código que obtive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir deste [site](http://blogwebdesignmicrocamp.com.br/programacao/php-instrucao-update-como-editar-os-registros/) indicado pelo @R.Santos, segui os passos e cheguei no seguinte código:

```
dados.php //(tela que exibe os registros do banco)

echo '<a href="edicao.php?id=' . $id . '"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>';
```

Nesta tela de dados eu capto o id do registro através do botão.

```
    edicao.php //(tela onde a o formulário de edição)

    <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

    <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="POST" action="php/editar.php">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" required="required" value="<?php echo $exibe['nome'] ?>">  
    ?>
```

Na tela de edição eu pego esse id que foi passado pela url e inicio a conexão, após, eu ajusto o formulário que chama o arquivo de edição e organizo os campos do banco nos campos do formulário.

```
    editar.php //(update nos campos)

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

    $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE pessoas SET id = '$id'

    mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Por fim, faço o update nos campos editados. Para mais detalhes é só acessar  site que tem tudo bem explicado.

Answer (score 0):

No botão deve haver um indicativo de qual registro você quer editar.
Por exemplo: No registro 1 no link do botão deve ter algo do tipo (href="minha-tabela/editar.php?id=$id-do-registro")